# I want to get all the results on page load before entering search query in React Js using elasticsearch

Tags: javascript, reactjs, search, elasticsearch, infinite-scroll

I want to display all the results as soon as page loads, before entering search terms. after the search terms are entered, the results should come accordingly. I'm using elastic search to display results via React Js.

Here is my code :

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import LazyLoad from 'react-lazy-load';

let i = 1;


class SearchResults extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { results: [] }
} 

render () {
    return (
        <div className="search_results">
            <hr />
            <ul>
            { this.props.results.map((result) => {
                return (
                            <li key={ result._id + i++}>
                                <LazyLoad className="lazy">
                                    <img className="image" src={<API URL> + result._source.file_name} alt="Search Result" />
                                </LazyLoad>
                            </li>
                        ) }) }      
            </ul>
            <button type="button" className="btn btn-default">Load More</button>
        </div>
    )
}
}

SearchResults.propTypes = {
    results: PropTypes.array
}

export default SearchResults;
```

I have set size=20 and I want from at every 20 requests. Please help me. Thank you.

For now, It only shows first 20 results. I want it to show more results by using infinite scroll.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to change your query to account for your paging.
Have a look at [ES paging](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/pagination.html).

Comment: The Query is Fine. I am unable to understand how to display all the results by default, even before searching